# independence of individual test methods in APITest class in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I followed the tutorial for testing from APITestCase documentation in dry site. But I could find answers to some of my doubts in the drf document.

I have a APITestCase subclassed as below

```
class GroupTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        .
        .

    def tearDown(self):
        .
        .

    def test_case_A(self):
        .
        # I create a group here
        # but I dont delete the group object in case A
        .

    def test_case_B(self):
        .
        # Will the group object from case A exist in case B ?
        # are the different test methods in a APITestCase independent?
        .
```

If I have two test cases in GroupTest class, are they independent? will a group object created in case A affect case B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, each test will run on clean database. If you need some entities in DB - add them in setUp (they will be awailable across all test cases in class), or directly in test case.

After testcase execution, all changes are rolled back. If you have some other changes to be undone (for example, you create some files) - do this in tearDown.

Answer (score 0):

Tests are good place for experiments. It's easy and fun to make some temporary tests to check some assumptions.

For example, to get the answer to your question, you can make 2 simple tests cases, each of them should to create some instance and to check if the instance created in other test exists (use `print()` commands to see what's going on).

Comment: Thanks. I am already playing with test cases. I just just got confused because i didn't know that setUp and tearDown gets called around every test method. Now i am going through unit test doc to understand more about testing in python